# django rest frameworks - querying to a nested List?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Working with DRF and curious as to whether you can query over a nested item like a list.   For example, being able to filter against a query parameter like: `http://someurl.com?hashtags=cool`

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "author": 1,
    "hashtags": [
        "cool", "gross"
    ],
    "username": "johndoe"

}
```

I have checked out Django Filters, and was looking for something DRF-specific,  kind of like:
`hashtags = django_filters.filters.CharFilter(name="hashtags")` but for iterating over a nested List. Obviously `CharFilter` wouldn't be correct.

Thanks for any tips or ideas.

-Updated-

The filter obviously does not work but, what was where I was trying to go

views.py

```
class MentionLatFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    hashtags = django_filters.filters.SomeFilter(name="hashtags")

    class Meta:
        model = Mention
        fields = ['hashtags']


class MentionList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MentionSerializer  
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = MentionLatFilter       


    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Mention.objects.all()
        placename = self.request.query_params.get('placename', None)
        if placename is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(placename=placename)

        username = self.request.query_params.get('username', None)
        if username is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(username=username)  

        return queryset
```

models.py

```
class Mention(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    username =  models.CharField(max_length=140, default='Username')
    placename = models.CharField(max_length=140, default='SOME STRING')
    placemention = models.TextField(max_length=140, default='SOME STRING')
    lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=15)
    lng = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=15)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
            blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.placename



class Hashtag(models.Model):
    mention = models.ForeignKey(Mention, related_name='hashtags')
    tagname = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('mention', 'tagname')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.tagname)
```

Comment: Your question is really not clear. What do you mean by *query like: `http://someurl.com?hashtags=cool`*? That's not a query. That's a url. Do you mean to filter the queryset based on the queryparam?

Comment: @RohitJain Sorry, yes.  filtering against query parameters, but specifically a List

Comment: Can you show how your models look like? and your view? Specially what type of field is `hashtags`?

Comment: @RohitJain updated the question with my views and models.py

Comment: Why do you need custom filter here? Did you try `Mention.objects.filter(hashtag=hashtag_filter)`? Where `hashtag_filter` is `kwargs.get('hashtags')`.

Comment: Check this out: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Comment: ah, ok. For some reason I was under the impression I could only achieve this through a custom filter. Will let you know on my progress. Thanks

Comment: Check my answer.. Use `hashtag__tagname` for tag name comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a custom filter here. Django queryset can follow the reverse relationship very well, for filtering. Check this link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Here's how you would modify your `get_queryset()` method:

```
class MentionList(generics.ListAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        hashtag_filter = self.request.query_params.get('hashtags', None)
        return Mention.objects.filter(hashtag__tagname=hashtag_filter)
```

Comment: Cool I think i would just have to adjust  ```hashtag__tagname``` to ```hashtags__tagname```  though, right?

Comment: @gregdevs No, it would be `hashtag__tagname` only. For reverse field lookup, you just use lowercase class name.

Comment: also, I would have to expand a bit on this so hashtag_filter can iterate over that nested list right? otherwise this would just return result based on  just the first item in list, right?

Comment: @gregdevs No. It would return you all the `Mention` objects, where `hashtag` list has at least 1 hashtag with name `hashtag_filter`. Please run this logic, and see if it works as expected.

Comment: Sounds good, checking it out shortly. Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Yup this worked although, i did have to adjust the ```hashtag_tagname``` line to plural.   Thank you again for the insight and the solution

Comment: @gregdevs you sure you've to use `hashtags_` instead of `hashtag_`? Documentation says later should work. Can you try removing the related_name from `HashTag` foreign key relation?

Comment: Yup im sure, just tried.  But, should'nt that be the case since the field is named ```hashtags``` and not ```hashtag```  ?

Comment: @gregdevs `hashtags` is the related name. The filtering should work on lowercased class name as per docs. Do you still have custom filter there when you tried this?

Comment: No custom filtering, however I forgot to mention on my MentionSerializer I have a create method that uses ```hashtags``` to create Array (via ```related_name```)

Comment: @gregdevs You can use `hashtag_set` for related name which you get by default. It's good to follow that as standard, than having your custom related names.